# Obj-C: C functions declared inside or outside @implementation block, what's the difference?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa-touch

what's the difference between a C function (static or not) declared inside or outside the implementation block (@implementation ... @end) of a Objective-C class?

is this specially true?:

> If you need to poke inside of the object directly, you can put this function inside of the @implementation block of your class, and then you can access instance variables with the C arrow operator. But that’s kind of naughty, so to preserve your Purity of Essence you should be using method calls on your object. End of Sermon. Here’s the evil:

```
@implementation OblateSphereoid

void drawEggThunk (DrawingContext *context, Rect areaToDraw, void *userData)
{
BWOblateSphereoid *dealie = (BWOblateSphereoid *)userData;
dealie->_frognatz = [NSColor plaidColor];
// and more stuff.
} // drawEggThunk

...
@end // OblateSphereoid
```

can i access instance variables of my class within functions (declared in the same class) in this way?

Comment: Upvoted for being an interesting question (although perhaps very bad practice) Just out of curiosity, you can only call drawEggThunk from within your class?

Comment: i can't, the function is a callback function called from a C subsystem, as you can see i use *userData for passing a reference to self when callbacks are setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is legal, I don't understand why it's required in the kind of case you've described (and it is an ugly solution). Why can't you just call:

```
[dealie setFrognatz:[NSColor plaidColor]];
```

If you don't usually provide a `-setFrognatz:`, just make it a private method by declaring it inside the .m, but above this function definition. (It doesn't actually matter if it's in the `@implementation` block in this case.)

```
@interface BWOblateSphereoid ()
- (void)setFrognatz:(NSColor *)acolor
@end

@implementation OblateSphereoid

void drawEggThunk (DrawingContext *context, Rect areaToDraw, void *userData)
{
    BWOblateSphereoid *dealie = (BWOblateSphereoid *)userData;
    [dealie setFrognatz:[NSColor plaidColor]];
    // and more stuff.
} // drawEggThunk

...
@end // OblateSphereoid
```

There are a few places where `->` notation can be helpful. The most critical is in implementing `-copyWithZone:` where it can be [absolutely required](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmImplementCopy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000049-997407) (a requirement that really emphasizes why I hate any ObjC code that plays with raw memory like `NSCopyObject()` does). But I recommend against `->` in most cases for the same reasons I always recommend accessors. Even in the case where you need to pass an ivar by reference to a C function (another common use of `->`), I prefer using a temporary and then assigning it afterwards.

I consider the fact that ivars are not `@private` by default to be a bug in ObjC.... I put `@private` at the top of every `@interface` block and have avoided several nasty bugs that way.

BTW, your solution as written may be leaking an `NSColor`. Maybe it is, maybe it's not, but an accessor would be certain.

Comment: The "private" method is the answer for the underlying problem (access ivars within functions without break encapsulation) :) but ... there's some difference between functions inside and outside @impementation?

Comment: by the way, objc ivars are by default @protected, this is the perfect scope: visible for the class itself and subclasses, and hidden for all the rest.

Comment: There's no difference between inside and outside @implementation.

Comment: I disagree that subclasses should be able to see the ivars of their superclass. They should be using accessors (and ObjC needs @protected on methods so we could implement that more easily). Access to your superclass's ivars leads to a nasty bug opportunity (which I've had burn me). You hoist a superclass but forget to remove the ivar releases from the subclass dealloc. When you dealloc, you and your superclass release the ivar and you crash. @private catches that at compile time. You should always use accessors for everything, so there's little good reason to access your superclass's ivars.

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine if its inside your @implementation. I'd recommend you make it a normal method, but it works.

If you put it out of your implementation, you get this warning: Warning: instance variable '' is @protected; this will be a hard error in the future. You can avoid this error by putting a @public before your iVar in the header... like so:

```
@public 
int myInt;
```

That allows you to access the variables like a C (pointer) Struct wherever the object appears without warning.

So its doable, not recommended though!!!

Comment: i think this may be a bad practice too, but i don't want to expose the ivar as public just in favor of encapsulation, but my C callback functions must be capable of see the instance ivars.

Comment: Then you should do what you have to do... you don't have to declare all your iVars as public, you can mix and match.